# Invariant ring of linear algebraic groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, invariant-theory, geometric-invariant-theory

Let $G$ be a connected linear algebraic group. This question concerns Hilbert's 14th Problem for the adjoint action of $G$ on itself.  Let $k[G]^G$ denote the algebra of  regular functions on $G$ invariant under the conjugation action. It is well-known that if $G$ is reductive, then $k[G]^G$ is finitely generated and that it is in fact a polynomial algebra on $r$ generators, where $r$ is the reductive rank of $G$. The main question concerns non-reductive groups:

**Question**: Is $k[G]^G$ always finitely generated? If not, can we give a necessary/sufficient criteria for when it is finitely generated? Can one "describe" $k[G]^G$ even if it is not finitely generated?

For instance, what does the invariant ring for the group $U_n$ of $n\times n$ unipotent upper triangular matrices look like?

Comment: The following statement is a particular case of [arXiv:1605.00800](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.00800.pdf). (Everything is over an algbraically closed field $k$ of characteristic zero.) Let $U \subseteq {\rm GL}_n$ be the unipotent radical of a Borel. Let $\mathfrak{n}$ be the Lie algebra of $U$, so that $U$ acts on $\mathfrak{n}$ via the adjoint action. Then $k[\mathfrak{n}]^U$ is finitely generated. As far as I understand, in some other paper of the same author the ring of invariants is described more explicitly. This seems kind of similar/related to your last question.

Comment: Thanks Alexlvanov...It seems in Theorem 4.3 of this paper, it is proved that $k[\mathfrak{n}]^U$ is actually a free polynomial algebra. I cannot figure out if this paper is published.

Comment: I think for $U_n$ one can check that the ring of invariants is generated by the entries that are just above the diagonal, by inductively checking that invariant functions must be independent of the top-right entry, then the next two entries, then....

Comment: @WillSawin So are you saying that we should have $k[\mathfrak{u_n}]^{U_n}=k[E_{1,2}^*, ..., E_{n-1,n}^*]$?

Comment: For $U_n$ an argument is also given in Section 2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.00447.pdf.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: @WillSawin and Dr.Evil: by the way, is there some clear relation between $k[Lie G]^G$ and $k[G]^G$ (adjoint actions)? It seems that for G = U_n we even have $k[\mathfrak{u}_n]^{U_n} = k[U_n]^{U_n}$ (probably this should follow using Will Sawin's explicit description, or some log/exp maps, which make sense since the group is unipotent). On the other side, I cannot see why such equality should hold for $G = GL_n$. This seems to me like a reasonably general question.

Comment: @Dr.Evil: Unfortunately, I don't know whether the paper is published or not, I just found it on arxiv. Sorry!

Comment: @AlexIvanov In characteristic zero, the log/exp maps give an isomorphism between their formal completions. That's the only relationship I know.